Utilizar un diccionario en javascript con django
Tengo un diccionario:
data = {
    "nombre": "Juan",
    "edad": 30,
    "ciudad": "Ciudad de México"
}

Que se pasa a la template:
return render(request, 'index/template.html', data)

Y quiero saber como puedo usarlo desde plantilla con javascript:
He probado algo asi pero no funciona para django 5
let data= "{{ data| json | safe }}"


A la hora de pasar el diccionario vamos a pasarlo como JSON
return render(request, 'index/template.html', json.dumps(data))

Y lo recuperaremos en javascript con escapejs
let data = JSON.parse('{{ data| escapejs }}');

Una vez recibido ya podremos mostrar por consola sus campos por ejemplo:
console.log(data.nombre)

o tambien:
console.log(data[0])

